# does oracle.sql.ARRAY save sequence of passed elements?

Tags: java, database, oracle

I can't find a proof link for a question:
if oracle.sql.ARRAY saves sequence of elements passed in constructor

```
public ARRAY(oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor, java.sql.Connection connection, java.lang.Object o) throws java.sql.SQLException
```

Where Object o is actually an array of elements. Can you help me, please?!

Comment: What is a proof link?  What is your actual question?

Comment: Proof link is a link to web page were it is written by api creator (or may be someone who made some tests to proof the statement) that this way (SELECT column_value AS id FROM TABLE (CAST (? AS ids_tab))) binded oracle.sql.ARRAY saves sequence of array elements passed in constructor in 3rd parameter (i.e. Object o). Fex: if I pass in Object o: [1,2,3,4] array will be binded in SQL in the same order, so in select I'll have: 1,2,3,4. Sorry if it was not clear previously.

Comment: Is there a sensible cause _not_ to save the order of elements? How could you use such API? /* Also: past tense of 'bind' is 'bound'. */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off the example in your comment:

```
SELECT column_value AS id FROM TABLE (CAST (? AS ids_tab))
```

In SQL, one should never assume that a row source will be returned in any particular order, except as specific by an ORDER BY clause.  Even if the ARRAY object stores items in the sequence they were originally given (which I would expect to be the case), there is no rule that the SQL engine has to retrieve them in that order.

Unfortunately, since the array has no key value, there is no `ORDER BY` that you can use to enforce that its elements will be returned in their original order.